# Dynamic binding in SQL

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to bind variable dynamically in my SQL query, which i am trying to execute through java.

For this,  I successfully constructed the below query using data binding :

```
select HOST,PORT, VIRTUAL_HOST, CLUSTER from XYZ where TYPE='abc' and NAME=?
```

But for queries like :

```
select HOST, PORT, VIRTUAL_HOST, CLUSTER from PQR where TYPE='abc' and NAME IN (?)
```

How can I use dynamic binding for IN statements ? 
Here the value of the binding variables that i have with me is a String with comma seperated values  such as NAME IN (I, J,K)

Where i already have a parameter :
String temp = "I,J,K".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do it dynamically this way :

```
  StringBuilder scmd = new StringBuilder (128);
  scmd.append ("SELECT HOST, PORT, VIRTUAL_HOST, CLUSTER ");
  scmd.append ("FROM PQR ");
  scmd.append ("WHERE TYPE='abc' ");
  if (names.length > 0) {
    scmd.append ("AND NAME IN (");
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0)
        scmd.append (',');
      scmd.append ('?');
    }
    scmd.append (")");
  }
  PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(scmd.toString());
```

Where `names` is a String array that contains a variable number of values.

Then you can assign the values :

```
  if (names.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      stmt.setString (i + 1, names[i]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need one question mark per element, ad there's no way around it (except by using a wrapper API like Spring JDBC which does it for you):

```
String sql = "select HOST, PORT, VIRTUAL_HOST, CLUSTER"
             + " from PQR where TYPE='abc' and NAME IN (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, "I");
stmt.setString(2, "J");
stmt.setString(3, "K");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also write your own workaround to accomplish the same as the NamedParameterStatement in JDBC:

```
public class NamedParameterStatement {

    // define the parameter format as a colon followed by at least one word letter
    private final String PARAMETER_REGEX =":\\w+";

    // the parsed sql query string containing question marks,
    // not named parameters
    private String sql;

    // hashtables for parameter mapping
    private Hashtable<String, Integer> parameterNameMap;
    private Hashtable<Integer, Object> parameterValueMap;



    /**
     * constructor for named parameter statements
     * @param namedParameterSQL the sql query with named parameters
     */
    public NamedParameterStatement(String namedParameterSQL) {
        // init hashtables
        this.parameterNameMap = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
        this.parameterValueMap = new Hashtable<Integer, Object>();

        // create a matcher for the named parameter sql query based on 
        // the pattern specified for the named parameter format
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
                PARAMETER_REGEX,
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                .matcher(namedParameterSQL);
        int i = 1;
        while(m.find()) {
            // watch out: this implementation does not check
            // for multiple parameters with the same name.
            parameterNameMap.put(m.group().replace(":", ""), i++);
        }
        // replace all named parameters with question marks
        this.sql = m.replaceAll("?");
    }



    /**
     * creates a prepared statement for the specified connection,
     * based on the parameter mapping
     * @param conn the database connection
     * @return a prepared statement
     * @throws SQLException thrown on error with preparing the statement
     * @throws InvalidBindingException thrown on errors with the parameter binding
     */
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection conn)
            throws SQLException, InvalidBindingException {
        // check if bindings match
        if(parameterNameMap.size() == parameterValueMap.size()) {
            // create prepared statement
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(this.sql);
            // for each parameter binding, set the parameter and its index accordingly
            for(Integer i : this.parameterValueMap.keySet()) {
                Object value = this.parameterValueMap.get(i);
                // map the parameter object types against the different parameter setters
                // this mapping is incomplete!!! just a proof of concept.
                if(value.getClass() == String.class) {
                    ps.setString(i, (String) value);
                } else if(value.getClass() == Integer.class || value.getClass() == int.class) {
                    ps.setInt(i, (int) value);
                } else if(value.getClass() == Double.class || value.getClass() == double.class) {
                    ps.setDouble(i, (double) value);
                } else if(value.getClass() == Long.class || value.getClass() == long.class) {
                    ps.setLong(i, (long) value);
                }
            }
            return ps;
        }
        else throw new InvalidBindingException("Not all parameters were bound.");
    }



    /**
     * returns the converted prepared statement query string
     * @return the query string
     */
    public String getSQL() {
        return this.sql;
    }



    /**
     * binds a parameter value to a parameter name
     * @param parameter the parameter name
     * @param value the parameter value
     */
    public void bindParameter(String parameter, Object value) {
        // check if the parameter name existed in the named parameter query string
        if(this.parameterNameMap.containsKey(parameter)) {
            this.parameterValueMap.put((Integer)this.parameterNameMap.get(parameter), value);
        }
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter '" + parameter + "' does not exist.");
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
NamedParameterStatement nps = new NamedParameterStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1=:param1 AND column2=:param2");
nps.bindParameter("param1", "value1");
nps.bindParameter("param2", 2);
PreparedStatement ps = nps.createPreparedStatement(conn);
ResultSet results = ps.executeQuery();
while(results.next()) {
    System.out.println(results.getString("column1"));
}
```

I know, this is not ideal either, but it does the trick if you do not want to use JDBC or other frameworks (Hibernate, ...).